# Eagle CAD hide TL081 unused pins

Tags: eaglecad

I am using a TL081 IC, just the +, - and out pins (plus power supplies). I would like to hide the unused pins (offset and disconnected). Which is the right way to do this?

EDIT: and what should I do with the unused terminals? Just leave them floating?

Comment: You shouldn't leave them floating (and therefore shouldnt delete the pins in the part): https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/1957

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a part with offset and enable pins, then you should show them in the schematic.  You shouldn't be doing what you're trying to do.

I understand they add clutter and you probably don't want to show them for that reason.  However, they are part of the chip, so you should show what you're doing with them, even if it's just leaving them unconnected (I haven't looked to see if that is appropriate or not, example only).  Otherwise, the schematic and board don't match, which will cause confusion to anyone who works with both, including you a few months or years from now.

Don't play games with shortcuts like this.  In the end they will cost you more time and trouble than dealing with them properly up front would have.

Comment: I agree with this answer 250%. I cannot tell you how many times I've been involved in projects where engineers tried to play games with hiding part pins on schematics only to get PC boards made where something did not work as intended. It is so common that multiple gate logic parts do not show the pwr and gnd pins on the schematic symbol and this leads directly to some parts not getting connected correctly; particularly on modern computer boards where there are 2, 3 or even 4 different power planes in use. So make sure to ALWAYS show all pins on the symbols. This should be done (continued)

Comment: (continued from above) even if it means having to re-draw the common library parts in the schematic package and creating your own private library.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the device in the library. To do that, right click on the part, open device and then edit symbol (schematic view) or edit package (pcb view)

Answer (score 0):

The data sheet http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/snosbw6a/snosbw6a.pdf doesn't say anything about connection(s) of un-used pins. Their examples do not show all pins connected. Therefor, I would edit the Eagle part also.